# nhibernate lazyload creates new isession

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, isession

Can I prevent nhibernate creating new ISessions when lazy loading? How?

Correction: I mean new IDbConnections. I have implemented my own DriverConnectionProvider and I see it gets called due to lazy loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using NHibernate as a connection manager and sql generator. I.e. you have a lot of code like the following:

```
public IList<Entity> GetEntities()
{
    using (ISession session = CreateNewSession())
    {
        return session.List<Entity>();
    }
}
```

Then you cannot use lazy loading. So you will need to disable lazy loading. This can be most easily achieved by specifying `default-lazy="false"` on your hibernate-mapping tag
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-mapping

I might recommend using an IStatelessSession instead of the default ISession as well. Keep in mind that this is not the recommended use of NHibernate.

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate does not create any `ISession` by its initiative. Please post some example in which you feel this happen. The underlying  connection is actually opened during a lazy fetch just because NH needs to connect to the database in order to fill lazy collections/associations.

Comment: Sorry I mean new IDbConnections. I have implemented my own DriverConnectionProvider and I see it gets called due to lazy loading.